# html text without tag

Tags: javascript, html

How can i remove html text without tag ?
Remove :

```html
<div>
  ***remove***
  <p>A car is a wheeled, self-powered motor vehicle used for transportation.</p>
  ***remove***
  <p>A car is a wheeled, self-powered motor vehicle used for transportation.</p>
  ***remove***
  <p>A car is a wheeled, self-powered motor vehicle used for transportation.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what kind of result your expecting here. Its not much clear

Comment: What do you mean by remove? Do you mean dynamically or just deleting it?

Comment: Please explain your question in brief.How you want to remove and wanna completely remove or wanna hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a simple solution just for your case.

```
var content = $("div").find("p");
$("div").empty().append(content);
```

Comment: Working but jQuery has not been precised in post

Answer (score 1):

Element nodes are of [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) 1, so you can iterate through all `childNodes` and `.remove()` those which do not have a `.nodeType` of `1`, ensuring that only elements are preserved:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
[...div.childNodes].forEach((node) => {
  if (node.nodeType !== 1) {
    node.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  ***remove***
  <p>A car is a wheeled, self-powered motor vehicle used for transportation.</p>
  ***remove***
  <p>A car is a wheeled, self-powered motor vehicle used for transportation.</p>
  ***remove***
  <p>A car is a wheeled, self-powered motor vehicle used for transportation.</p>
</div>
```

Less elegant, but you can also create an array of the `.children` to get all element children, then clear the container and append all the element children again:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const children = [...div.children];
div.textContent = '';
children.forEach(child => div.appendChild(child));
```

```html
<div>
  ***remove***
  <p>A car is a wheeled, self-powered motor vehicle used for transportation.</p>
  ***remove***
  <p>A car is a wheeled, self-powered motor vehicle used for transportation.</p>
  ***remove***
  <p>A car is a wheeled, self-powered motor vehicle used for transportation.</p>
</div>
```